# On iOS how to view the tweets of a particular user in Twifferific and Tweetbot

Tags: ios, applications, twitter

Let's say I found in a bio the twitter handle `@BarackObama` (or even a less popular one) and I want to quickly look at the tweets of this user.

I'm having a hard time finding an easy way to do this in [Twitterrific](https://twitterrific.com/ios). Is it possible? How do I do it?

Plus I'm thinking of switching to [Tweetbot](https://tapbots.com/tweetbot/) - how do i do it in this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tweetbot you can easily do it the following way:

Go to the search tab and use the “Users with“ option. Than type type (or paste) the twitter handle (e.g. @BarackObama). At the top of te search results you find the profiel of that person. Tap on it and go to tweets.

This works quite similarly in the [official Twitter app](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8).